# Solve $\log_x (4x^{\log_5 x} + 5) = 2log_5 x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**My attempt**

$\log_5(4x^{log_5x}+5)=2(log_5x)^2$      Using $\log_ab=\frac{\log_cb}{\log_ca}$

$4x^{log_5x}+5=5^{2(log_5x)^2}$

Let $f=x^{log_5x}\Rightarrow \log_5 f = (log_5x)^2 \Rightarrow f= 5^{(\log_5 x)^2} $

We arrive at,

$ 4 *5^{(\log_5 x)^2}+5=5^{2(log_5x)^2};$        Let $5^{(\log_5 x)^2} = z$

$z^2-4z-5=0$
It gives;

$z=-1, 5$

$z=5$ gives $x=5, \frac{1}{5}.$ [Real solution]

$z=-1$ gives $5^{\sqrt{\log_5 (-1)}} = -0.0941629 - 4.90284 I$   [Complex solution]

Ques: I am suspecting that this complex solution should not be there, Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is so simple, check the domain and range of
$$5^{(\log_5 x)^2}$$

We know that
$$(\log_5 x)^2\ge0$$
So,
we get
$$5^{(\log_5 x)^2}\ge1$$
or $$z\ge 1$$

So,
$$z=5 $$ is the only solution.

Comment: oh!, I missed this point. thank you very much